# Any walking tours (in English) in Cologne or nearby?

Tags: germany, tours, cologne

I'll be in Cologne, Germany a few days this summer.

Usually when I'm staying alone in a city (assuming I have time) I'll try to find a walking tour of some sort as it gives me an opportunity to meet other travelers as well as do some sightseeing. I'm, however, not meeting with any success in Cologne.

Can anyone point me at a walking tour, in or near Cologne? I'm prepared to take a train ride as far as one hour away so options in nearby cites, such as Bonn, are valid answers.

It needs to be suitable for a single person joining a tour. I have found a few where you can book a walking tour for an entire group of people, but that is obviously unsuitable for me. And it needs to be in English. My German isn't nearly good enough for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ultimately found one walking tour in the region, in Bonn to be specific. The website is [here](http://www.bonn.de/tourismus_kultur_sport_freizeit/tourist_information_aktuell/tourismus_und_hotels/stadttouren/01367/?lang=en).

As the details are buried in a PDF I'll quote them here.

> **Bonn - Roman Settlement, Baroque Residence  and Beethoven City
> Discover Bonn´s numerous sights on a walking  tour through the
> historical city centre**
>
> The historical centre of Bonn offers an abundance of sights  which are
> easily reached on foot. The major points are the  Beethoven monument,
> the romanesque Minster Cathedral, the Electors palace (nowadays the
> University) with the  elegant Hofgarten and the baroque City Hall. The
> tour also  takes you to the banks of the Rhine, near the Opera, from
> which river excursions on the boats of the Weiße Flotte  (white fleet)
> are possible. The imposing view of Germany´s  oldest nature park
> Siebengebirge (seven hills) can be seen  from the banks of the Rhine.
> The tour ends at Ludwig van  Beethoven‘s birthplace in the Bonngasse.
> Here you have the opportunity to visit Beethoven´s birthplace with the
> Digital Beethoven House on your own. The  entrance fee must be paid
> separately at the Beethoven  House.
>
> **Date and Time:** Saturdays from 27 April to 26 October  at 11 am
> **Meeting place:** Bonn-Information, Windeckstraße 1/ am
> Münsterplatz
> (nearby Minster Cathedral Square)
> **Duration:** around 1 ½ hours
> **Price:** Adults 9 €, with reduction 5 € (children aged 12-17, students, disabled)

I didn't find out until after I payed, but tour is actually conducted in German and also in English if there are English speaking people joining the tour. As I was the only English speaker in the tour it felt a bit awkward, but the tour was still very interesting and I would recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

Expedia actually has tours on their site, occasionally.

In this instance, it appears as though [they have one for Cologne](http://www.expedia.co.uk/pub/agent.dll/nojs=1/qscr=tsdt/ofid=4831/loid=179998/stat=5/wtid=28/).

However, it's only on Fridays, and the English one is at 4.30pm, and runs for 1.5 hours.

Comment: Unfortunately, even though that link takes you to a description of a walking tour, searching for any specific dates turns up no results. Seems it is not being offered at the moment :(

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the offical website for Tourism in Cologne. They have many offers:

http://www.cologne-tourism.com/guided-tours.html

Comment: Be careful, some of these tours seem to be offered to already formed groups.

Answer (score 3):

[eat-the-world.com](http://www.eat-the-world.com/en/tours-cologne/booking/suedstadt-tour.html) offers guided tours with food stops. The english one is only on Fridays.

If you decide to visit Bonn you can join a [Bonn for Beginners Guided Tour](http://www.stattreisen-bonn.de/bonnforbeginners.htm).
Another interesting option is to visit [the former German Bundestag in Bonn](http://www.bonn-region.de/english/sightseeing/capital-era-international-bonn/guided-walking-tours.html). There are guided tours on Saturdays, Sundays and holidays. However it's not a walking tour.

Answer (score 2):

Dont forget the [Freewalk Cologne](http://freewalkcologne.com) walking tour.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a Free walking tour in Bonn as well. I've participated the last Friday, it was fun
they now have a Fb group but I found them on Instagram @bonn.city.tour

https://www.facebook.com/Bonn-City-Tours-1894469937543127/?fref=ts